# Getting unexpected outputs in java program

Tags: java

i have made a java program for school that allows customers to buy train tickets. everything works perfect so far except, when i call the final method (current final method there will be more eventually) it prints what i have commanded the method to print but it also outputs some random lines of text and i cant figure out when. **i will paste the program code below** and i will also show the console when i run the program up to the point. i will try and highlight the problem. thank you very much and i hope someone can help.
p.s. the program should end at "test".

```
    import java.util.Scanner; //imports the scanner class to allow for user input

public class ticketPurchase {
    //Adding global variables to be used by various methods
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String menuChoice;
    static double childTicket = 1.20;
    static double adultTicket = 2.50;
    static double adultFlexi = 12.00;
    static double childFlexi = 8.00;
    static String ticketType;
    static String ticketChoice;
    static int adultTicketQty;
    static int childTicketQty = 0;
    static String destinationZone;
    static double adultFinalPrice;
    static double childFinalPrice;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu(); //calling the menu method within the main method to start the process
    }
    public static void menu() {
        System.out.println("Press 1 for information");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to purchase Standard Tickets");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to purchase Flexi tickets");
        menuChoice = input.next(); //allowing user to choose what tickets to buy or just to see information of services

        switch(menuChoice) { //switch statement to record and output information based on users input
        case "1":{ //prints information regarding pricing, ticket age restrictions and support
            System.out.println("The standard ticket may be a single or return ticket for an adult (16+) or a child");
            System.out.println("The flexi ticket covers all journeys for one 24 hour period for either a child or an adult");
            System.out.println("A single ticket's price depends on the journey length, single or return and if it is for an adult or a child");
            System.out.println("a Flexi ticket for a child costs €8.00 and a Flexi ticket for an adult costs €12.00");
            System.out.println("Our Customer Care telephone number for this terminal is 0830462920, please call if further support is required");
            break;
        }
        case "2":{
            ticketChoice = "standard"; //records the value of standard within the ticketChoice global variable
            chooseTickets(); //initiates the choose tickets method
            break;
        }
        case "3":{
            ticketChoice = "flexi"; //record the value of flexi within the ticketChoice global variable
            chooseTickets(); 
            break;
        }
        case "a":{ //allows user to enter the admin interface 
            admin();
            break;
        }
        default:{ //allows for user to input a value outside of the options and notify's them to try again
            System.out.println("Invalid choice, please choose from 1 to 3");
            break;
        }
        }
        menu(); //recursion
    }
    public static void chooseTickets() { //payment method for choosing adult or child and quantity, and purchasing.
        System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketChoice + " ticket(s)");
        System.out.print("Enter 1 for an adult ticket, Enter 2 for a child ticket: "); 
        String ticketAgeGroup = input.next(); //assigns users choice to string variable
        switch(ticketAgeGroup) { //allows user to choose quantity and destination based on choice of adult or child
        case "1":{//case for adult tickets
            System.out.println("you have chosen adults ticket");
            ticketType = "adult";
            System.out.print("Please enter the quantity of tickets: ");
            adultTicketQty = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("please enter your destination zone (1, 2, 3, 4): ");
            destinationZone = input.next();
            if(ticketChoice == "flexi") { //if statement to calculate the finalPrice variable value if the ticketChoice is Flexi
                adultFinalPrice = (adultFlexi*adultTicketQty);
            }
            else {
                adultFinalPrice = (adultTicket*adultTicketQty); //else calculates the finalPrice variable value if the ticketChoice is standard
            }
            switch(destinationZone){ // switch statement to calculate the final price depending on the destination's zone and their extra amount.
            case "1":{
                adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*0); 
                break;
            }
            case "2":{
                adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*.50); //calculation to add the extra amount for the destination
                break;
            }
            case "3":{
                adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*1.0);
                break;
            }
            case "4":{
                adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*1.50);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("you have entered an invalid choice please choose from 1 to 4");
                //recursion if the user enters an invalid choice 
                break;
            }
            } //end of the switch statement
            System.out.println("The total price for your purchase is €" + adultFinalPrice ); 

            System.out.print("Would you like to purchase more tickets? enter 1 if so, 2 if not: "); //allows user to purchase other tickets 
            String moreTicketChoice = input.next();
            if(moreTicketChoice.equals("1")) {
                chooseTickets();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("you have chosen against purchasing more tickets");
            }
            payment(); //initiates the payment method after user has chosen quantity and ticket type etc
        }

        case "2":{ //case for children's tickets
            System.out.println("you have chosen children's ticket");
            ticketType = "child";
            System.out.println("Please enter the quantity of tickets: ");
            childTicketQty = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("please enter your destination zone (1, 2, 3, 4): ");
            destinationZone = input.next();
            if(ticketChoice == "flexi") { //adjusts the price if user chooses the flexi option 
                childFinalPrice = (childFlexi*childTicketQty);
            }
            else {
                childFinalPrice = (childTicket*childTicketQty);
            }
            switch(destinationZone){ //adjusts price to account for the destination's zone chosen by user
            case "1":{
                childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*0);
                break;
            }
            case "2":{
                childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*.50);
                break;
            }
            case "3":{
                childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*1.0);
                break;
            }
            case "4":{
                childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*1.50);

                break;
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("you have entered an invalid choice please choose from 1 to 4");
                chooseTickets();
                break;
            }
            }
            System.out.println("The total price for your purchase is €" + childFinalPrice );
            System.out.print("would you like to purchase more tickets? enter 1 if so, 2 if not: "); //allows user to purchase other tickets 
            String moreTicketChoice2 = input.next();
            if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("1")) {
                chooseTickets();
            }
            else if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("2")){
                System.out.println("you have chosen against purchasing more tickets");
            }
            payment();
        }
        default:{
            System.out.println("you have entered an invalid choice please enter 1 or 2");
            chooseTickets();
            break;
        }

        }

    }
    public static void payment() { //method to complete the payment process for the purchase
        System.out.println("test");

    }
    public static void printTickets() { //method to notify the customer that their tickets are printing 

    }
    public static void admin() { //method to control the admin's interface

    }
}
```

**this is the error i have when i run the program (doesnt end in "test" and im not sure whats causing that)**

Press 1 for information

Press 2 to purchase Standard Tickets

Press 3 to purchase Flexi tickets

2

You have chosen to purchase standard ticket(s)

Enter 1 for an adult ticket, Enter 2 for a child ticket: 2

you have chosen children's ticket

Please enter the quantity of tickets:

2

please enter your destination zone (1, 2, 3, 4): 2

The total price for your purchase is €3.4

would you like to purchase more tickets? enter 1 if so, 2 if not: 2

you have chosen against purchasing more tickets

**test** --need program to stop here (temporarily)

***you have entered an invalid choice please enter 1 or 2

You have chosen to purchase standard ticket(s)

Enter 1 for an adult ticket, Enter 2 for a child ticket:***

Comment: `if(ticketChoice == "flexi")` -- no. Rather `if (ticketChoice.equals("flexi"))`

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: You don't `break;` after calling `payment();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using recursion after printing test the stack of the method call should get you back to :

```
case "2":{
        ticketChoice = "standard"; //records the value of standard within the ticketChoice global variable
        chooseTickets(); //initiates the choose tickets method
        break;
    }
```

and after that menu() will be call again.
so i can suggest that you run add an exit functionality that uses exit() or put the code inside of a do while loop that uses a boolean flag in order to get out.

also you forgot to put break after payment() method.

here is the modified code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {
    //Adding global variables to be used by various methods
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String menuChoice;
    static double childTicket = 1.20;
    static double adultTicket = 2.50;
    static double adultFlexi = 12.00;
    static double childFlexi = 8.00;
    static String ticketType;
    static String ticketChoice;
    static int adultTicketQty;
    static int childTicketQty = 0;
    static String destinationZone;
    static double adultFinalPrice;
    static double childFinalPrice;
    static boolean shouldBeRunningAgain = true;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu(); //calling the menu method within the main method to start the process
    }
    public static void menu() {
        do {
            System.out.println("Press 1 for information");
            System.out.println("Press 2 to purchase Standard Tickets");
            System.out.println("Press 3 to purchase Flexi tickets");
            menuChoice = input.next(); //allowing user to choose what tickets to buy or just to see information of services

            switch (menuChoice) { //switch statement to record and output information based on users input
                case "1": { //prints information regarding pricing, ticket age restrictions and support
                    System.out.println("The standard ticket may be a single or return ticket for an adult (16+) or a child");
                    System.out.println("The flexi ticket covers all journeys for one 24 hour period for either a child or an adult");
                    System.out.println("A single ticket's price depends on the journey length, single or return and if it is for an adult or a child");
                    System.out.println("a Flexi ticket for a child costs €8.00 and a Flexi ticket for an adult costs €12.00");
                    System.out.println("Our Customer Care telephone number for this terminal is 0830462920, please call if further support is required");
                    break;
                }
                case "2": {
                    ticketChoice = "standard"; //records the value of standard within the ticketChoice global variable
                    chooseTickets(); //initiates the choose tickets method
                    break;
                }
                case "3": {
                    ticketChoice = "flexi"; //record the value of flexi within the ticketChoice global variable
                    chooseTickets();
                    break;
                }
                case "a": { //allows user to enter the admin interface
                    admin();
                    break;
                }
                default: { //allows for user to input a value outside of the options and notify's them to try again
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice, please choose from 1 to 3");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }while (shouldBeRunningAgain);
    }
    public static void chooseTickets() { //payment method for choosing adult or child and quantity, and purchasing.
        System.out.println("You have chosen to purchase " + ticketChoice + " ticket(s)");
        System.out.print("Enter 1 for an adult ticket, Enter 2 for a child ticket: ");
        String ticketAgeGroup = input.next(); //assigns users choice to string variable
        switch(ticketAgeGroup) { //allows user to choose quantity and destination based on choice of adult or child
            case "1":{//case for adult tickets
                System.out.println("you have chosen adults ticket");
                ticketType = "adult";
                System.out.print("Please enter the quantity of tickets: ");
                adultTicketQty = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("please enter your destination zone (1, 2, 3, 4): ");
                destinationZone = input.next();
                if(ticketChoice.equals("flexi")) { //if statement to calculate the finalPrice variable value if the ticketChoice is Flexi
                    adultFinalPrice = (adultFlexi*adultTicketQty);
                }
                else {
                    adultFinalPrice = (adultTicket*adultTicketQty); //else calculates the finalPrice variable value if the ticketChoice is standard
                }
                switch(destinationZone){ // switch statement to calculate the final price depending on the destination's zone and their extra amount.
                    case "1":{
                        adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (0);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "2":{
                        adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*.50); //calculation to add the extra amount for the destination
                        break;
                    }
                    case "3":{
                        adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*1.0);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "4":{
                        adultFinalPrice = adultFinalPrice + (adultTicketQty*1.50);
                        break;
                    }
                    default:{
                        System.out.println("you have entered an invalid choice please choose from 1 to 4");
                        //recursion if the user enters an invalid choice
                        break;
                    }
                } //end of the switch statement
                System.out.println("The total price for your purchase is €" + adultFinalPrice );

                System.out.print("Would you like to purchase more tickets? enter 1 if so, 2 if not: "); //allows user to purchase other tickets
                String moreTicketChoice = input.next();
                if(moreTicketChoice.equals("1")) {
                    chooseTickets();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("you have chosen against purchasing more tickets");
                }
                payment(); //initiates the payment method after user has chosen quantity and ticket type etc
            }

            case "2":{ //case for children's tickets
                System.out.println("you have chosen children's ticket");
                ticketType = "child";
                System.out.println("Please enter the quantity of tickets: ");
                childTicketQty = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("please enter your destination zone (1, 2, 3, 4): ");
                destinationZone = input.next();
                if(ticketChoice.equals("flexi")) { //adjusts the price if user chooses the flexi option
                    childFinalPrice = (childFlexi*childTicketQty);
                }
                else {
                    childFinalPrice = (childTicket*childTicketQty);
                }
                switch(destinationZone){ //adjusts price to account for the destination's zone chosen by user
                    case "1":{
                        childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (0);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "2":{
                        childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*.50);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "3":{
                        childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*1.0);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "4":{
                        childFinalPrice = childFinalPrice + (childTicketQty*1.50);

                        break;
                    }
                    default:{
                        System.out.println("you have entered an invalid choice please choose from 1 to 4");
                        chooseTickets();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("The total price for your purchase is €" + childFinalPrice );
                System.out.print("would you like to purchase more tickets? enter 1 if so, 2 if not: "); //allows user to purchase other tickets
                String moreTicketChoice2 = input.next();
                if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("1")) {
                    chooseTickets();
                }
                else if(moreTicketChoice2.equals("2")){
                    System.out.println("you have chosen against purchasing more tickets");
                }
                payment();
                break;
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("you have entered an invalid choice please enter 1 or 2");
                chooseTickets();
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    public static void payment() { //method to complete the payment process for the purchase
        System.out.println("test");
        shouldBeRunningAgain = false;

    }
    public static void printTickets() { //method to notify the customer that their tickets are printing 

    }
    public static void admin() { //method to control the admin's interface

    }
}
```

hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much the recursion of the menu method was causing much of the issue like you said. sometimes its hard to keep track of all that i've done which is why i add the comments! thanks again, working great now